# ExpressJS- GET method -Json data - Angular 4+

Tags: node.js, angular, express, get

This question might be duplicate. apologizes for that. am trying to console.log json data from "Server"  folder. PFA folder structure.

[image]

### server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors  =  require ( 'cors' );
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const data = require('./mydata.json');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(cors());

app.get('/getMyData', (req,res)=>{
  /*res.json(data);
  console.log ( 'from inside of get method, data==>',data.msg )*/     
})
console.log ( 'from outside of get method, data==>',data.msg )

app.listen(3005, () => {
  console.log ( 'Server running' )
});
```

After that am trying to call the endpoint inside service in my Angular app.

The problem is, I can see the content of JSON file out the GET method, but inside method.

Could someone tell me how to get from `mydata.json` file and load it to view? At least I need to log it my console window.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

put the require inside:

```
app.get('/getMyData', (req, res) => {
  const myData = require('./mydata.json');
  res.json(myData.example);
})
```

Your console.log() is only visible at the console from your server.
You can use monolog for server side logging: https://www.npmjs.com/package/monolog there is a example middlerware explained for express.

Comment: could you pls tell me how to consume data from that file?

Comment: Set it inside your funtion to a property, then you can access as normal JavaScript-Object.

Comment: But be sure, that the data in your json file is a valid json. You can test it with tools like that: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: ll give my try and let you know and really thanks for your time